# Старый проект на новой версии Android Studio и Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Есть старый проект, который был сделан пару лет назад. Соответственно и Android Studio и Gradle тоже того времени.
Сейчас стоит все свежее.
Проект сохранялся путем "Export to Zip".
Сейчас (на всем свежем) при открытии проект начинает качать старый Gradle.
Как импортировать проект, но чтобы он уже был на новом Gradle?

Comment: никак. Пусть скачает, потом сам предложит использовать новый

Comment: @Эникейщик а где поменять все зависимости? и где вообще хранится Gradle? хочу тогда скачать - поменять - удалить неактуальный Gradle.

Comment: Всё можно: при стандартных настройках версия грэдла указана в файле `<ProjectDir>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Скачанные дистрибутивы хранятся в `<UserDir>/.gradle/wrapper/dists`, старые удаляются самим грэдлом по принципу кеширования. Также можно сразу сменить версию AGP в файле `<ProjectDir>/build.gradle`

Comment: @woesss теперь он начинает ругаться на зависимости и import'ы =(

Comment: @Wlad,  естественно - с тех пор произошло не мало изменений и нужно теперь адаптировать проект к новым условиям. В зависимостях, вероятно, нужно заменить `compile` на `implementation`, подробнее про зависимости можно почитать: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: @woesss т.е. путь с наименьшим сопротивлением это скачать олдовый gradle, сделать что надо и удалить старый gradle ?

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите делать с этим проектом. Если просто посмотреть, потестить, чуть подправить, то да - лучше не трогать никакие настройки. Но если надо серьёзно заняться проектом, проапгрейдить под новую версию ОС  - то по любому придётся всё апгрейдить.

Comment: @woesss а разве версия ОС зависит от этого? несколько лет я работал в одной и той же Studio и с одинм и тем же Gradle, переходя на новые API без проблем. а вот установив новую Studio (на другой комп) и оставшись на той же версии ОС - вот такие проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ №1. Выкачать старый Gradle**
Просто импортируем проект, Studio сама скачает Gradle, на котором был сделан проект.
Потом она ругнется на buildToolsVersion и предложит либо:
а) повысить версию Gradle до актуального (зачем тогда качали старую?)
б) скачать buildToolsVersion версии старого проекта.

Можно, кстати, самому исправить buildToolsVersion на ту, которая имеется.
По итогу мы имеем 2 версии Gradle, 1 из которых занимает 500-600 Мб ради одного проекта.

**Способ №2. Подменить версию Gradle** *спасибо [@woess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss) за подсказку*
Тут нам понадобиться еще и "новый проект", который создан на текущей версии Android Studio, с текущим Gradle и buildToolsVersion.

Из корня этого проекта мы копируем в корень нашего старого проекта с заменой:
*gradle.properties

build.gradle*
*gradle* - целую папку

далее открываем в обоих проектах `.../app/build.gradle` и меняем в нашем "старом" нужные нам пункты: targetAPI, buildToolsVersion, minAPI и тд.

`dependencies {....}` не трогаем!!

теперь можно импортировать наш "старый" проект.
Studio нанчет сама докачивать некоторые `dependencies` но не критичного размера. у меня прибавилось лишь 10-15 Мб (по сравнению с 500 Мб целого старого `Gradle`!)
после Rebuild Project могут вылазить косяки с импортами. удаляем старые неактуальные импорты. среда начинает ругаться, например, AppCompatActivity красным. Alt+Enter - Import Class.

Еще у меня среда ругалась на constraintlayout в `activity_main.xml` (вернее она ругалась на строчку) `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Заменяем в activity_main.xml старый

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

на свеженький

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Немного нудный способ, да и скорее всего у него много подводных камней, которые еще у меня не всплыли.
Но так мы переносим проект на актуальный Gradle и экономим место.